# c# MVC dependency injection based on route param

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

What I'm trying to do is to instantiate a service using NInject and a route param.

I have something like this:

**DAL**

```
public interface IDALContract
{
  object GetById(int id);
}

public class DALPeopleContract : IDALContract
{
  public object GetById(int id)
  {
    //get person
    return null;
  }
}

public class DALAnimalsContract : IDALContract
{
  public object GetById(int id)
  {
    //get animal
    return null;
  }
}

public static class DALContractFactory
{
  public static IDALContract GetContract(int discriminator)
  {
    switch(discriminator)
    {
      case 1: return new DALPeopleContract();
      case 2: return new DALAnimalsContract();
      default: throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
  }
}
```

**Business Layer**

```
public interface IMyService
{
  object GetById(int id);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
  private IDALContract _contract;

  public MyService(int discriminator)
  {
    _contract = DALContractFactory.GetContract(discriminator)
  }

  public object GetById(int id)
  {
    return _contract.GetById(id);
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController
{
  private IMyService _myService;

  public MyController()
  {
    //how do I get the discriminator here? (the discriminator should be a route param)
    IParameter param = new Parameter("MyParam", discriminator, true);
    _myService = NInjectKernel.TryGet<IMyService>(param);
  }

  ActionResult Index(id)
  {
    _myService.GetById(id);
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

So the issue that I'm having is how to get the param, or is there a better approach to this. Basicaly what I'm trying to do is to have one controller that handles the same actions for different models, but I'm having an issue with the Data Access Layer (DAL).

Would it be a good idea to get the value on OnActionExecuting and instantiate there the service?

Comment: You are going down the path of tight coupling between person and animal. Even worse, a discriminator usually implies an inheritance relationship between the classes (and interfaces), but your concrete classes both implement the *same* interface. Frankly, I can't even imagine how a person and an animal can have the same fields in this scenario or even how they could be close enough to share the same interface. Note that if you separate people and animals into 2 different tables, all of your issues (your question, the fact that you are using service locator, tight coupling) will go away.

Comment: Animals and persons was just an example to simplify my code. My classes are related. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a clean (in my opinion) solution to my issue.

So now I have a fairly easy way to deal with simple operation on related classes.

I replaced the DALContractFactory with some NInject binding. And I have a custom route defined for my controller that requires a "type" that is read in OnActionExecuting on my controller.

For the models, I have a factory defined and a custom mapper (I haven't posted them here because they were not relevant to the question). If anybody is interested, I can post a sample sln with this approach.

So now I have something like:

**DAL**

```
public interface IDALContract
{
  object GetById(int id);
}

public class DALPeopleContract : IDALContract
{
  public object GetById(int id)
  {
    //get person
    return null;
  }
}

public class DALAnimalsContract : IDALContract
{
  public object GetById(int id)
  {
    //get animal
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Business Layer**

```
public enum Discriminator
{
    Animal,
    Person
}

public interface IMyService
{
  object GetById(int id);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
  private IDALContract _contract;

  public MyService(IDALContract contract)
  {
    _contract = contract;
  }

  public object GetById(int id)
  {
    return _contract.GetById(id);
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
  private IMyService _myService;

  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
  {
    base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
    int type;
    var routeValue = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["type"];

    Discriminator type;

    if(!Enum.TryParse<Discriminator>(routeValue.ToString(), out type))
    {
        //set a default value
        type = Discriminator.Animal;
    }

    _myService = NInjectKernel.Instance.GetService<IMyService>("type", type);
  }

  public ActionResult Index(id)
  {
    _myService.GetById(id);
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

**NInjectConfiguration**

```
public class NInjectKernel
{
  private readonly IKernel _kernel;
  private NInjectKernel()
  {
    _kernel = new StandardKernel();
  }

  private static volatile Irr2NInjectKernel _instance;
  private static readonly object SyncRoot = new object();
  public static Irr2NInjectKernel Instance
  {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (SyncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        var temp = new Irr2NInjectKernel();
                        temp.BindAllDependencies();
                        _instance = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private void BindAllDependencies()
    {
        _kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>();
        _kernel.Bind<IDALContract>().ToMethod(x =>
        {
            IParameter parameter = x.Parameters.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "type");
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                var recordType = (Discriminator)parameter.GetValue(x, x.Request.Target);

                switch (recordType)
                {
                    case RecordType.Animal:
                        return new DALAnimalsContract();
                    case RecordType.Person:
                        return new DALPeopleContract();
                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException("DQS type is not suppported.");
                }
            }
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        });
    }
}
```